# Virtualising a WIndows 95 PC on VirtualBox - No Bootable media found

Tags: virtualbox, virtualization, windows-95

I created a VHD of an ancient but still running Windows 95 PC using disk2vhd ( its used for printing reports from our almost as ancient pbx ) I'd like to virtualize it due to its age.

Installed VirtualBox but when booting from the VHD in Virtual box I get the following message

"Fatal: no bootable medium found! System Halted"

My Windows 95 skills are fairly rusty, any pointers on how to fix it greatly appreciated!

Comment: I booted to FreeDos from an iso and had a look at the partition in Fdisk, it looks as if there are no partitions defined but the disk is showing up and is the correct size

Comment: The error indicates the system is not bootable, this means the image you created is flawed, this is from the Virtual Box manual itself. **If there are no partitions define that would explain the reason its not bootable.** Why isn't that comment in the question itself? How did you use Disk2VHD to create the image, Windows 95 isn't supported, I am pretty sure Disk2VHD is a .NET application. You should be able to mount the VHD file and see its contents, if you can't do this, then the image isn't complete.

Comment: It was a while ago that I created the image, I think I plugged the harddrive into an XP machine and made the image that way. Attaching the VHD to my desktop shows its unallocated, I guess I'll have another go at grabbing the image

Comment: AFAICR Windows 95 CDs were never bootable - you had to have a separate boot diskette. I expect you can find a suitable boot image somewhere on the web, or perhaps someone created a way to make a bootable CD.